# What is a good bytes per second sent/received rate?

Tags: xna, networking, xna-4.0, xbox

I am working with XNA networking, on the XBOX.

I was wondering what is a safe number to stay under in the bytes sent and received when it comes to the xbox. Obviously various factors will effect the number, and you want as little packet data as possible to keep things smooth, but what is a good number for that?

(Using : [networksession.bytespersecondsent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.net.networksession.bytespersecondsent) and [networksession.bytespersecondreceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.net.networksession.bytespersecondreceived) to measure the number.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 kilobytes per second is the number I have seen tossed around on the AppHub forums. There is a short description of how headers and voice affect this number on [Shawn Hargreaves blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20140505193229/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/12/18/network-bandwidth-packet-headers.aspx).

Comment: I saw his topic, however it doesn't ever say what a good overall number would be.

Comment: The original talk Shawn gave, which is now several years old, can be downloaded at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=24865 If I remember correctly he goes over a slide where data collected from XBLA games recommended the 8kB/s limit

Comment: Oh, thank you! I hadn't seen that set of slides from him, another though, which was quite helpful but not quite as informative.